# Index out of range while converting from rdd to dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert spark RDD to dataframe. While RDD is fine when I convert it to dataframe I get index out of range error.

```
alarms = sc.textFile("hdfs://nanalyticsedge.com:8020/hdp/oneday.csv")
alarms = alarms.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
header = alarms.first()
alarms = alarms.filter(lambda line:line != header)
alarms = alarms.filter(lambda line: len(line)>1)
alarms_df = alarms.map(lambda line: Row(IDENTIFIER=line[0],SERIAL=line[1],NODE=line[2],NODEALIAS=line[3],MANAGER=line[4],AGENT=line[5],ALERTGROUP=line[6],ALERTKEY=line[7],SEVERITY=line[8],SUMMARY=line[9])).toDF()
alarms_df.take(100)
```

*Here alarms.count() works fine whereas alarms_df.count() gives index out of range. **It is data export from oracle***

From @Dikei's answer I found that:

```
alarms = alarms.filter(lambda line: len(line) == 10)
```

gives me proper Dataframe but why do dataframe get lost when it is database export and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thinks the problem is some of your lines do not contain 10 elements.
It's easy to check, try changing

```
alarms = alarms.filter(lambda line: len(line)>1)
```

to

```
alarms = alarms.filter(lambda line: len(line) == 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

No data with the index mentioned. Try something like, if the array has more than 9 print 10th element

```
myData.foreach { x => if(x.size.!=(9)){println(x(10))}  }
```